# Android studio Java class construction null object reference on sqlite database object

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I think this is an easy one, but I am a newcomer to constructing classes in Java. I'm working in Android studio and have the class which I've included in the code below.
The function in the class simply tries to do a query to a sqlite database, but I am getting the following error.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I imagine this is due to not properly declaring the sqLiteDatabase object. Can anyone help to explain how and where to correct this issue?

```
package com.example.zzzzz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class clsSqliteHandler {

    //SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("wildlife_db", MODE_PRIVATE,null);


    public clsSqliteHandler() {

    }


    public Cursor getCursor(String strTable, String strColsToReturn, String strSelectionWhere, String strSelectionArgs){

        String strTableName = strTable;
        String[] strColumnsToReturn = { strColsToReturn };
        String strSelectWhere = strSelectionWhere ;
        String[] strSelectArgs = { strSelectionArgs };
        Cursor csrResult = sqLiteDatabase.query(strTableName, strColumnsToReturn, strSelectWhere, strSelectArgs, null, null, null);

        return csrResult;

    }

}
```

here is how I call the class method from my activity...

```
        Cursor myCursor = mySqliteHandler.getCursor("fact_sightings", "animal_common_name", "province_name", "Western Cape");
```

Comment: You never assign a SQLiteDatabase object to the variable. Thus your variable references null and therefore the error throws when the method getCursor is called. You net to create such an object and assign it to your variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I've edited the post to include how I call the class function. Would you be able to elaborate on your comment and maybe suggest some code that would work? Thanks again

Comment: Where do you initalize the sqLiteDatabase variable in the clsSqliteHandler class? Your code does only show a declaration of that variable which is by default null in Java, if you don't assign an object to it. So it should be anything like that:

Comment: SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, I did try that but I got an error in the MODE_PRIVATE parameter, saying "cannot resolve symbol". I've edited the original code with the new sqlite declaration / initialization, where I now get the MODE_PRIVATE error. I think this has to do with context? Are you able to provide advice on this error?

Comment: I have got it to work using the following declaration: `    String databaseNameWithPath = "/data/data/" + "com.example.jdapp" + "/databases/" + "wildlife_db";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseNameWithPath, null);`